# How can i save payment data using a custom plugin in Woo Commerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Here is the deal, I am using my own plugin, which I am trying to use to post my checkout to the backend.

At the moment the only data that I can post is the order that comes from woocommerce (total price, address, product, etc.), but within my plugin I perform an echo in which I seek to capture the credit card data, or better still, tokenize that data.

Below it's one of my plugin functions that shows the input in my checkout page

```
    public function payment_fields() {

        if ( $this->description ) {
            if ( $this->testmode ) {
                $this->description .= 'In test mode';
                $this->description  = trim( $this->description );
            }
            echo wpautop( wp_kses_post( $this->description ) );
        }

        echo '<fieldset id="wc-' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-cc-form" class="wc-credit-card-form wc-payment-form" style="background:transparent;">';
     
        do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_start', $this->id );
                
        echo '<div class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label>Card Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="nookacard_ccNo" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                name="nookacard_ccNo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-row form-row-first">
                <label>Expiry Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="nookacard_expdate" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                placeholder="MM / YY">
              </div>
              <div class="form-row form-row-last">
                <label>Card Code (CVC) <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="nookacard_cvv" type="password" autocomplete="off" 
                placeholder="CVC">
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>';
        
         do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_end', $this->id );
     
         echo '<div class="clear"></div></fieldset>';
     
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot capture the data from that input, and I don't know how to do it either.

I can only capture the woocommerce data as I show below

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;
     
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $order_billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $order_billing_last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $order_billing_address1 = $order->get_billing_address_1();
        $order_billing_address2 = $order->get_billing_address_2();
        $order_billing_city = $order->get_billing_city();
        $order_billing_state = $order->get_billing_state();
        $order_billing_postcode = $order->get_billing_postcode();
        $order_billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
        $order_billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
        $order_billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
        $order_get_total = $order->get_total();
        $order_get_currency = $order->get_currency();
        
        $urlTest = 'http://4bbb948fe73b.ngrok.io/order';

        $body = array(
            'id' => $order_id,
            'billing' => array (
                'firstName' => $order_billing_first_name,
                'lastName' => $order_billing_last_name,
                'address1' =>   $order_billing_address1,
                'address2' =>   $order_billing_address2,
                'city' => $order_billing_city,
                'state' => $order_billing_state,
                'postcode' => $order_billing_postcode,
                'country' => $order_billing_country,
                'email' => $order_billing_email,
                'phone' => $order_billing_phone,
            ),
            'totalPrice' => $order_get_total,
            'currency' => $order_get_currency,
        );

        $args = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type'  => ' application/json',
            ),
            'body' => wp_json_encode($body),
        );
         $response = wp_remote_post( $urlTest, $args );
         $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
```

I already know that I am not capturing anything with the inputs, but I tried in different ways and I have no way of obtaining all the data by doing the same post route.

Comment: You can just read them from the `$_POST` variable during checkout submit. That a custom variable is not part of the `$order` object is nothing we need to talk about.

Comment: Thats my issue, i cant post data and my order object at the same time. u know how can i do it?